# Why are my files not available inside my Docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm running nginx inside a Docker container one an M1 Macbook.

As part of this, I'm trying to make some letsencrypt certificates available to it.

In my docker-compose file, I have

```
volumes:
  - ${PWD}/infrastructure/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
  - ${PWD}/logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx:rw
  - /private/etc/letsencrypt/live:/etc/letsencrypt/live
  - ${PWD}/apps/fallback-server/static:/var/www/apps/fallback-server/static
  - ${PWD}/apps/server/data/static-apps:/var/www/apps/server/data/static-apps
```

When I start the container, I see the following (newlines added for ease of reading:

```
web-proxy-1  | nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate
"/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: 
error:80000002:system library::No such file or directory:calling 
fopen(/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem, r) error:10000080:BIO routines::no such file)
```

Note that there's no complaint about missing `nginx.conf`.

My File Sharing is set up to include `/private`:

[image]

However, both the error message and this view of files, indicate that the files have not made it into the container:

[image]

All of my searching online tends to point to solutions that point to File Sharing, but as far as I can tell, that's set up correctly.

What steps can I take next to resolve this?

All of my searching online tends to point to solutions that point to File Sharing, but as far as I can tell, that's set up correctly.

One point worth noting is that if I run the service, `web-proxy`:

```
docker compose run -i -t web-proxy /bin/sh
```

I can see the files.

What steps can I take next to resolve this?

Comment: Can you provide the current context folder and the current docker file ?

Comment: There's no `Dockerfile` here. This is a Docker Compose issue. I'll update the tags accordingly

Answer (score 1):

It turns out several things were going on.

First, the files in `live/` are soft symlinks to `../../archive/`, so they won't work without that directory being mounted.

Second, those files are owned by root with highly restrictive permissions. Since I'm running Docker as a non-root user, the files are inaccessible to that process.

The solution (in this specific case) is to run `certbot` as the same user that I'm running Docker